IntelliJ Idea compilation issue with Gradle and QueryDsl
I am trying to use QueryDsl in a Gradle project (using Spring Boot), which, using the QueryDsl Gradle plugin by ewerk, works without problems: it creates a module querydsl in IntelliJ Idea, into which it generates the Q models when executing the Gradle task compileJava. These Q models can then be referenced in classes from the main module.
IntelliJ Idea, however, does not seem to take into account the dependencies for the querydsl module that Gradle provides:
https://github.com/tdinev/querydsl-intellij-issue/tree/master/docs/querydsl-module-dependencies.png
The main module has no dependency on the querydsl module, either:
https://github.com/tdinev/querydsl-intellij-issue/tree/master/docs/main-module-dependencies.png
This prevents a proper compilation in IntelliJ of the Q models
https://github.com/tdinev/querydsl-intellij-issue/tree/master/docs/q-model-compilation-error.png
as well as of any types referencing a Q model:
https://github.com/tdinev/querydsl-intellij-issue/tree/master/docs/compilation-error.png
Compilation in Gradle succeeds, this seems to be merely an IntelliJ Idea issue.
I could, of course, add the dependencies manually in the module dialog of IntelliJ Idea, but this setting is lost after executing Reload All Gradle Projects.
A minimal example is available in the master branch of https://github.com/tdinev/querydsl-intellij-issue.
I have tried the recipe given in https://dev.to/markliu2013/spring-boot-3-integrate-querydsl-with-gradle-2mfp, to no avail (check the branch no-plugin of the mentioned GitHub repo).
I have also tried several variations on
idea {
    module {
        sourceDirs = sourceDirs + setOf(file("generated-src"))
        generatedSourceDirs = generatedSourceDirs + setOf(file("generated-src"))
        configurations.querydsl.configure {
            extendsFrom(configurations.compileClasspath.get())
        }
    }
}

with no positive result, though.
Microsoft Copilot and Perplexity AI were not able to suggest a working solution, either.
Eclipse IDE (together with the Eclipse Gradle plugin) does not have this issue.
